# Celsius to Fahrenheit in Java

Tags: java

I can convert from fahrenheit to celcius, but not the other way around.  I have attached the code below.  Hopefully it's enough to see what is going on.

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {  
        double temps = 0, temp1 = 0;  
        String instrings;  
        instrings = temp.getText();  
        if(instrings.equals(""))  
        {  
            instrings = "0";  
            temp.setText("0");  
        }  
        temps = Double.parseDouble(instrings);  
        instrings = temp.getText();  
        if(instrings.equals(""))  
        {  
            instrings = "0";  
            temp.setText("0");  
        }  
        temp1 = Double.parseDouble(instrings);  
        if(arg0.getActionCommand().equals("C")){  
             temps = (( temps * 9)/5+32);  
             DecimalFormat formatters = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###.###");  
            results.setText(""+formatters.format(temps));  
        }  
        else if(arg0.getActionCommand().equals("F"));  
        {  
             temp1 = (((temps - 32)/9)*5);  
             DecimalFormat formatters = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###.###");  
            results.setText(""+formatters.format(temp1));  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: What is your code doing or not doing?  You are also trying to get a value from temp.getText and unless temp is a variable accessible to this class, I don't see how you will not get a null pointer exception

Comment: What is it doing and how is it different from what you want it to do?

Comment: What do you mean by you can't convert? Do you get an error or incorrect output?

Comment: @It Grunt:  I can enter in a degree in farenheit and it converts to celcius, but if I enter a degree in celcius it doesn't convert to farenheit.

Comment: @CoolBeans:  It does nothing unless I convert from farenheit to celcius.

Comment: please show the definition of the buttons (assuming that `actionPerformed` is called by pressing a button)

Comment: It's Fahrenheit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahrenheit. I fixed the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a

```
System.out.println(arg0.getActionCommand());
```

in your method, and supposedly you will see that it is not `"C"` when using the Celsius button.

Generally, look at the console to see if there are any error messages around.

---

Another idea: You are using two double variables `temps` and `temp1`, parsing the `instrings` into both of them, and setting then one of them to the result. Why so complicated?

---

In general, I would recommend to not use the `getActionCommand()` method, but to give each button an own ActionListener. You can use an anonymous class for this. As both cases do almost the same, use two subclasses of a inner (or even local) class here:

```
abstract class ConversionListener implement ActionListener {
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###.##");

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String input = temp.getText();
        if (input.equals("")) {
           input = "0";
           temp.setText(input);
        }
        double number = Double.parseDouble(input);
        results.setText(formatter.format(convert(number)));
    }
    /** to implement by subclasses */
    abstract double convert(double number);
}
celsiusToFahrenheit.addActionListener(new ConversionListener() {
    double convert(double celsius) {
        return number * 9 / 5 + 32;
    }
});
fahrenheitToCelsius.addActionListener(new ConversionListener() {
    double convert(double fahrenheit) {
        return (fahrenheit - 32) / 9 * 5;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are having trouble with but here is how to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit in Java.

```
float celsius = celsius value
float c=Float.parseFloat(celsius);
float f = 32 + 9*c/5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
temp1 = (((temps - 32)/9)*5);
```

to

```
temp1 = (((temps - 32)*5)/9);
```

instead.

Comment: What would this accomplish?  Those are the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

On this part:

```
instrings = temp.getText();  
        if(instrings.equals(""))  
        {  
            instrings = "0";  
            temp.setText("0");  
        }  
        temps = Double.parseDouble(instrings);  
        instrings = temp.getText();  
        if(instrings.equals(""))  
        {  
            instrings = "0";  
            temp.setText("0");  
        }  
        temp1 = Double.parseDouble(instrings);
```

Am I missing something or is temps and temp1 both getting set to the same value?  Or is it possible that between the temps assignment the temp.getText() could return a different value?

If it's the same, start by rewriting it to

```
    instrings = temp.getText();  
    if(instrings.equals(""))  
    {  
        instrings = "0";  
        temp.setText("0");  
    }  
    temps = Double.parseDouble(instrings);  
    temp1 = Double.parseDouble(instrings);
```

or even `temp1 = temps`

Also, some better naming of variables might be easier, temps, temp and temp1 are all very similar.  One appears to be text from a control and the other 2 are numeric values.

Even names like 'inputTemperature' and 'calculatedTemperature' go a long way to making the code more readable.

This doesn't help solve your problem, but might help debugging in the future.